# Elements in the coadjoint orbit are regular values?

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras, symplectic-geometry

Let $(M, \omega)$ be a symplectic manifold and let $G$ be a compact, connected Lie group acting on it. Let $J: M \rightarrow \mathfrak{g}^{*}$ be the moment map. Assume that $\eta$ is a regular value of $J$, and let $\mathcal{O}$ be the orbit of $\eta$ under the coadjoint action.

**Problem:** Prove that if $\zeta \in \mathcal{O} \subset \mathfrak{g}^{*}$, then $\zeta$ is a regular value.

**Attempt:** I know that $\zeta$ is a regular value iff $\forall p \in J^{-1} (\zeta)$, we have $\mathfrak{g}_p = 0$ where $\mathfrak{g}_p$ is the isotropy subalgebra. This is equivalent to saying $\mathfrak{g}_p^{0} = \mathfrak{g}^{*}$, where $\mathfrak{g}_p^{0}$ denotes the annihilator. I don't understand how to show that $\mathfrak{g}_p = 0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a consequence of the map $J:M\rightarrow\mathfrak{g}^{*}$ being equivariant. I will denote by $\phi_{g}:M\rightarrow M$ and $Ad_{g}^{*}:\mathfrak{g}^{*}\rightarrow\mathfrak{g}^{*}$ the $G$-actions on $M$ and $\mathfrak{g}^{*}$, respectively. Equivariance of $J:M\rightarrow\mathfrak{g}^{*}$ means that
$$
Ad_{g}^{*}\circ J = J\circ\phi_{g}\hspace{1cm}\forall g\in G.
$$
Choose $p\in J^{-1}(\zeta)$. Since $\zeta$ lies in the orbit of $\eta$, we there exists $g\in G$ such that $Ad_{g}^{*}(\zeta)=\eta$. Taking differentials in the above equality, we get a commutative diagram

$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
T_{p}M @>d_{p}J>> \mathfrak{g}^{*}\\
@V d_{p}\phi_{g} V V @VV Ad_{g}^{*} V\\
T_{\phi_{g}(p)}M @>>d_{\phi_{g}(p)}J> \mathfrak{g}^{*}
\end{CD}

Note that $J(\phi_{g}(p))=Ad_{g}^{*}(J(p))=Ad_{g}^{*}(\zeta)=\eta$. Since $\eta$ is a regular value, the bottom map in the diagram is surjective. Since the vertical maps are isomorphisms, also the top map is surjective.

Answer (score 0):

In case of non-null cohomology, Jean-Marie Souriau has studied affine action of coadjoint operator with an additional term related to the (Souriau) symplectic cocycle.
See: https://www.mdpi.com/1099-4300/22/5/498/pdf